# Count only rows with 30 minutes between each other?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to think of the most efficient way to count specific rows in a MySQL table.

My table contains a `datetime` column called `date_time` and I want to count the number of rows where there is at least 30 minutes between each `date_time`.

For example, lets say I have the table below:

```
id    date_time
1     2013-08-23 00:30:00    
2     2013-08-23 00:45:00    
3     2013-08-23 01:01:00    
4     2013-08-23 02:30:00    
5     2013-08-23 02:45:00
```

If I only want to include an entry if there is at least 30 minutes since the last entry, then the count would include id #1 and id #4, thus the count would be 2.

I am trying to come up with a clean script to do this, is there any special kind of query that will help me accomplish this?

Comment: Did you mean 30 seconds? Because your data is surely in seconds.

Comment: Do you mean first entry? And when you mean "thus the count would be 2" do you mean that you want to limit it to 2 results? Because I don't know how you would choose only id 1 and id 4 since there are others that are more than 30 seconds after id 1.

Comment: @Prix ahh i meant minutes, i apologize. I will update immediately. Thanks mike, the table has thousands of rows, so I do not want to limit to two. I also meant minutes...

Comment: Are you only interested in "30 minutes between _this row_ and the _next row_"? For example, in the sample data above only row `id 3` would be a valid result? Would this be a correct assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple solution for that is use `DATE_FORMAT` MySQL function.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b793/4

**Query**

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(`datef`, '%i') AS `Fields`,
  `datef`
FROM `dates`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`datef`, '%i') = 30
```

Comment: does it worked for you..?

Comment: This will just output all entries with "30" in the minutes - like 11:30:56, 12:30:23, etc... how can this answer have 2 likes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL variables (**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c01726/2)**):

```
SET @x := NULL;
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT @x AS prev, @x:=date_time AS curr
    FROM mytable
    ORDER BY id
) y
WHERE curr > prev + interval 30 minute
   OR curr < prev
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Assumes that the table is named "time_list" and the ids and times are sequential...

```
SELECT
  count(1)
FROM `time_list`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `time_list` AS `a`
    ON (`time_list`.`id` = (`a`.`id` + 1))
WHERE (
  (to_seconds(`time_list`.`date_time`) - to_seconds(`a`.`date_time`)) / 60 >= 30
  OR `a`.`id` IS null);
```